# Reduce is not giving answers, only verifies it's true

Tags: equation-solving

I'm trying to find a range for `{q1,q2}` with the conditions listed such that `U1R >= U1S`

```
U1R[q1_,q2_] = 2q1 + q2 + 3(1-q1-q2)
U1S[q1_,q2_] = q1 + 3q2 + 2(1-q1-q2)

Reduce[ForAll[{a,b}, 0 <= a <= 1 && 0 <= b <= 1 && a + b <= 1, 
  Exists[{x,y}, 0 <= x <= 1 && 0 <= y <= 1 && x + y <= 1, U1R[x, y] >= U1S[a, b]]], 
 {x,y}, Reals]
```

However, I'm only getting `True` for my output. I am expecting something like

```
.5 < x < .6 && .3 < y < .7
```

as my output. Why am I only getting true and not what makes that true? Thanks.

Comment: Your expression states that for any choice of a and b given constraints one can find an x and y with certain constraints. Mathematica certifies that this statement is indeed true. There's not more to this. If you want to have the right answer you have to ask the right question. The question in this case would be something like `Reduce[0 <= a <= 1 && 0 <= b <= 1 && a + b <= 1 && 0 <= x <= 1 && 
  0 <= y <= 1 && x + y <= 1 && U1R[x, y] >= U1S[a, b], {x, y}, Reals]`

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries That's a good answer, I think

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries Thank you! Could you explain why this gives the desired result:

`Reduce[ForAll[y, y >= 0, Exists[z, z >= 0, U1R[w, y] < U1R[z, y]]], {z}, Reals]` as this gives values for which it's true, but follows the same logic. Thank you again

Comment: @belisarius OK, moved it to an answer and elaborated a bit.

Answer (score 2):

Your expression states that for any choice of a and b given constraints one can find an x and y with certain constraints. Mathematica certifies that this statement is indeed true. There's not more to this. If you want to have the right answer you have to ask the right question. The question in this case would be something like:

```
Reduce[0 <= a <= 1 && 0 <= b <= 1 && a + b <= 1 && 
       0 <= x <= 1 && 0 <= y <= 1 && x + y <= 1 && 
       U1R[x, y] >= U1S[a, b], {x, y}, Reals
]
```

You also asked why then

```
Reduce[ForAll[y, y >= 0, Exists[z, z >= 0, U1R[w, y] < U1R[z, y]]], {z}, Reals]
(* w > 0 *)
```

gives a definite result, although it is also using `ForAll` and `Exists`.

This is because you introduce a variable/parameter `w` here, which is not bound to an `Exists` (or `ForAll`) and hence the truth of this statement depends on its value. When Mathematica checks this, it finds that a solution exists only for `w > 0`. Had you put `w` in the `Exists` as well, Mathematica would have determined the existence of solutions, and would therefore have responded with `True`, because that's all what `Exists` is about. It's not about specifications of solutions, but of their existence.

You may want to study the difference between

```
Reduce@Exists[w, w > 1] 
(* True *)
```

and

```
Reduce@Exists[x, w > 1]
(* w > 1 *)
```

In the former case, we ask Mathematica whether solutions exist for `w` making the second argument `True`. It is easy to see that is the case, so the answer must indeed be `True`. In the latter case the answer depends on the unbound `w`, so we cannot know whether there is an x for which the second argument is True unless we assume that, indeed, `w > 0`.

Other cases that may be helpful:

```
Reduce@Exists[x, w x > 1]
(* w < 0 || w > 0 *)

Reduce@Exists[{x, w}, w > 1]
(* True *)

Reduce@Exists[x, w + x > 1]
(* w ∈ Reals *)

Reduce@Exists[{x, w}, w + x > 1]
(* True *)
```